# sqlite3.OperationalError: table product has no column

Tags: python, sqlite

I downloaded python simple inventory system 
It had 3 columns: product name, product quantity and product price
I went through and added product location everywhere the other 3-product name, product quantity and product price  were in the program.
Now when it runs I get this error: 
sqlite3.OperationalError: table product has no column named product_location

Someone suggested remove  IF NOT EXISTS, FROM (CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS) but that did not work.

````
PASSWORD = StringVar()
PRODUCT_NAME = StringVar()
PRODUCT_PRICE = IntVar()
PRODUCT_QTY = IntVar()
PRODUCT_LOCATION = IntVar()
SEARCH = StringVar()```



I downloaded python simple inventory system from ```https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/python/11417/python-simple-inventory-system.html.```
It had 3 columns: product name, product quantity and product price. 
I want to use at work but I need product location as well. I went through and added product location everywhere the other 3 were in the program. There were some other things I changed but don’t recall all of them.
Now when it runs I get this error: 
```sqlite3.OperationalError: table product has no column named product_location.```





I have looked at this page ``https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run`` which has a lot about this problem but it is over my head.  I don’t usually work with code nearly this big.  Wondering if someone could give me an idea what to try that I may understand. 

Someone suggested remove  if not exist from create table but that did not work

def Database():
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect("pythontut.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (admin_id INTEGER 
    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username TEXT, password TEXT)")
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (product_id INTEGER 
    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, product_name TEXT, product_qty TEXT, 
    product_price TEXT)")
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = 'admin' AND 
    `password` = 'admin'")
    if cursor.fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `admin` (username, password) 
        VALUES('admin', 'admin')")
        conn.commit()

def AddNewForm():
    TopAddNew = Frame(addnewform, width=600, height=100, bd=1, relief=SOLID)
    TopAddNew.pack(side=TOP, pady=20)
    lbl_text = Label(TopAddNew, text="Add New Product", font=('arial', 18), 
    width=600)
    lbl_text.pack(fill=X)
    MidAddNew = Frame(addnewform, width=600)
    MidAddNew.pack(side=TOP, pady=50)
    lbl_productname = Label(MidAddNew, text="Product Name:", font=('arial', 
    25), bd=10)
    lbl_productname.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    lbl_qty = Label(MidAddNew, text="Product Quantity:", font=('arial', 25), 
    bd=10)
    lbl_qty.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    lbl_price = Label(MidAddNew, text="Product Price:", font=('arial', 25), 
    bd=10)
    lbl_price.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    lbl_productlocation = Label(MidAddNew, text="Product Location:", font= 
    ('arial', 25), bd=10)
    lbl_productlocation.grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    productname = Entry(MidAddNew, textvariable=PRODUCT_NAME, font=('arial', 
    25), width=15)
    productname.grid(row=0, column=1)
    productqty = Entry(MidAddNew, textvariable=PRODUCT_QTY, font=('arial', 
    25), width=15)
    productqty.grid(row=1, column=1)
    productprice = Entry(MidAddNew, textvariable=PRODUCT_PRICE, font= 
    ('arial', 25), width=15)
    productprice.grid(row=2, column=1)
    productlocaton = Entry(MidAddNew, textvariable=PRODUCT_LOCATION, font= 
    ('arial', 25), width=15)
    btn_add = Button(MidAddNew, text="Save", font=('arial', 18), width=30, 
    bg="#009ACD", command=AddNew)
    btn_add.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, pady=20)

def ViewForm():
    global tree
    TopViewForm = Frame(viewform, width=600, bd=1, relief=SOLID)
    TopViewForm.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
    LeftViewForm = Frame(viewform, width=600)
    LeftViewForm.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    MidViewForm = Frame(viewform, width=600)
    MidViewForm.pack(side=RIGHT)
    lbl_text = Label(TopViewForm, text="View Products", font=('arial', 18), 
    width=600)
    lbl_text.pack(fill=X)
    lbl_txtsearch = Label(LeftViewForm, text="Search", font=('arial', 15))
    lbl_txtsearch.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
    search = Entry(LeftViewForm, textvariable=SEARCH, font=('arial', 15), 
    width=10)
    search.pack(side=TOP,  padx=10, fill=X)
    btn_search = Button(LeftViewForm, text="Search", command=Search)
    btn_search.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=X)
    btn_reset = Button(LeftViewForm, text="Reset", command=Reset)
    btn_reset.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=X)
    btn_delete = Button(LeftViewForm, text="Delete", command=Delete)
    btn_delete.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=X)
    scrollbarx = Scrollbar(MidViewForm, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scrollbary = Scrollbar(MidViewForm, orient=VERTICAL)
    tree = ttk.Treeview(MidViewForm, columns=("ProductID", "Product Name", 
    "Product Qty", "Product Price", "Product Location"), 
    selectmode="extended", height=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set, 
    xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
    scrollbary.config(command=tree.yview)
    scrollbary.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    scrollbarx.config(command=tree.xview)
    scrollbarx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    tree.heading('ProductID', text="ProductID",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Product Name', text="Product Name",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Product Qty', text="Product Qty",anchor=W)
    tree.heading('Product Price', text="Product Price",anchor=W)
    tree.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
    tree.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
    tree.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
    tree.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
    tree.column('#4', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
    tree.pack()
    DisplayData()
````

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing conn = sqlite3.connect("pythontut.db") to
conn = sqlite3.connect("user.db")